# add citation information in R package

Tags: r, package, devtools

I am building my R package using `Roxygen2` and `devtools`, and I would like to add some citation information in my `R` codes (i.e. I hope to write in a `.R` file from which the citations can be auto-generated). The ultimate goal is to display, once I run the command `citation(MyPkgName)`, the citations of the **R package** as well as the citation (preferrably with BibTeX entry) of **the paper** I submit. Is there a way to do that using `devtools`? Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear to me.  Are you writing a package?  Does creating a CITATION file not do what you want?

Comment: @Dason: yes, I am writing an R package and hope to include the citation information, but I don't know how to do that...

Comment: Learn by [stealing from someone else](https://github.com/trinker/reports/blob/master/inst/CITATION).  I personally break into Hadely and Dason's GitHub all the time to figure what to do with docuemntation.  This file goes in your inst director.

Comment: @TylerRinker: thanks a lot! I learned how to do that and put a CITATION file in the `inst` folder

Comment: Check out the Citations page of Hadley's [R Packages][http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/inst.html] guide for more examples.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `CITATION` file should be in the `inst` directory. See the [official documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#CITATION-files) for details of what should be in the file.

Answer (score 22):

A file called "CITATION" needs to be created in the directory "yourPackage/inst/". The file `CITATION` can be created automatically with

```
usethis::use_citation()
```

This file will contain an unfilled template with blank fields for citation information (e.g., author, journal, year, etc.) You need to fill in the gaps.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to include citation in your package is during attach time (e.g. when using `library()`).

You can do so using the function `.onAttach()` (it could go in a `zzz.R` file, as suggested in [Hadley's R Packages book](https://r-pkgs.org/)).

One example, would be:

```
.onAttach<-function(libname, pkgname){
      packageStartupMessage('Please cite this paper!') 
}
```

But you can easily search for other examples in the net, as [this one](https://rdrr.io/cran/blockmodeling/src/R/onAttach.R) including a call to `citation()`.

Comment: I prefer if the packages do not print out unnecessary messages when being loaded. Providing information for citation() call is enough.